# What is the "[" binary file in my "/bin" folder for? (MacOS Big Sur M1 chip)

Tags: macos, operating-system

I am newbie in Operation System, and trying to catch up by exploring my new computer.

This morning,  I was just exploring the bin file, and I saw a weird folder called "[". What is this?
[image]

I did not create or install anything in the "/bin" folder yet. So it was not created by me. What is the "[" binary file in my "/bin" folder for?

[image]

Comment: To find out, you should try `man [` .  (If you do not know man, than you could also try `man man`)

Comment: Thank you! Its NAME is "test, [ -- condition evaluation utility"
Its DESCRIPTION is "The test utility evaluates the expression and, if it evaluates to true,
     returns a zero (true) exit status; otherwise it returns 1 (false).  If there
     is no expression, test also returns 1 (false)."

It seems like something that is built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[` is the test program. As the man page suggests, it's used like

```sh
[ condition ]
```

and evaluates to either a zero (for true) or a non-zero value (for false). In the case of zsh on macOS, the man page says that false is represented by 1. Note that the whitespace after the square bracket is important since that whitespace indicates to the shell that you want to run the `[` program.

Despite the presence of the program, that executable is probably not used often. It appears that you're using zsh, which is the default shell on macOS. In zsh, `[` is a built-in which takes precedence over `/bin/[`. This can be verified by

```sh
% which -a [
[: shell built-in command
/bin/[
```

The man page for the built-in can be found by `man zshbuiltins`.

If you want to explicitly use the program in `/bin`, then your command should look like

```sh
/bin/[ condition ]
```

### Example

Supposed you're running a shell script where you want to check a condition. For example, you want to check whether a file exists. `[` is frequently used for this purpose. Here is an example

```sh
if [ -f myFile.txt ]; then
   date > myFile.txt
else
   echo "File was created on $(cat myFile.txt)."
fi
```