# What is /bin/[ in macos Big Sur? Don't remember seeing an executable like that before

Tags: unix, macos-big-sur

I was poking around a new MacBook Air M1 running Big Sur. I came across an executable file in /bin called "[". Seemed strange to me so I looked into it a bit more but the mystery remains. Google/DuckDuckGo searches are fruitless. I copied the file into my homedir to do some more investigation. Here's what I found:

```
user@jackrabbit(s003) ~ % file foo
foo: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64]
[arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e]
foo (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
foo (for architecture arm64e):  Mach-O 64-bit executable arm64e
user@jackrabbit(s003) ~ % strings foo
@(#)PROGRAM:test  PROJECT:shell_cmds-216.60.1
33333
$FreeBSD$
missing ]
unexpected operator
%s: %s
closing paren expected
argument expected
%s: bad number
%s: out of range
@(#)PROGRAM:test  PROJECT:shell_cmds-216.60.1
33333
k@$FreeBSD$
missing ]
unexpected operator
%s: %s
closing paren expected
argument expected
%s: bad number
%s: out of range
user@jackrabbit(s003) ~ %
```

I tried running the executable with a few different arguments but didn't get any useful output.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=code%3A%22%2Fbin%2F%5B%22) of [What is the “\[” binary file in my “/bin” folder for? (MacOS Big Sur M1 chip)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65522634/4642212).

Answer (score -2):

After some more thinking and poking around, it's a copy of /bin/test. It's got the same size and last modified time, so it appears to be part of the original OS install. Anyone with Big Sur able to verify if they also have /bin/[?